GPG Decyrption from Powershell
I am trying to decrypt files with GPG from powershell. It has been painful... my command works fine interactively or from the POWERSHELL ISE in Debug Mode. However as soon as I run the PS Script from Task Scheduler it runs and gets to the part of the script where I call GPG.exe and nothing happens. I see GPG fire up in the process but nothing happens. It should Decrypt the file and output as a text file.
 #Call gpg4win to decrypt files in "E:\BannerAWS\SAPConcur\Production\"

$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path "E:\BannerAWS\SAPConcur\production" -Filter "*.pgp"
Write-Log "Beginning Decrpytion on $Files.Count"


if ($Files.Count -ge 1)
{
    ForEach ($file in $Files) 
    {
        #C:\Scripts\DecryptConcur.bat
        $OutPut = $file.fullname.SubString(0, $File.FullName.length -4)
        Copy-Item -Path $file.fullname -Destination $BackUpGPG 
        & "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe" -v --batch --pinentry-mode=loopback --passphrase "$PassPhrase" -d -o $OutPut $file.FullName
         Start-Sleep -seconds 1
         

             
         if (Test-Path $OutPut) 
        {
            Write-Log "Deleting File $File" 
            Remove-Item $File.fullname
            Write-Log "Copying Decrypted File to Archive."  
            Copy-Item -Path $OutPut -Destination "E:\BannerAWS\SAPConcur\archiveproductiontest\"
        }
        Else
        {   
            if(-Not (Test-Path $OutPut))
            {Write-Log "Decrypted File was never created."}
        }
    }
    Write-Log "Calling Load Script"
    #C:\scripts\loadfzrsaetproduction.bat
    Write-Log "Load Script ran and complete see log at c:\scripts\fzrsaetlog.txt"
}
Else
{
    Write-Log "No Files to Decrypt Found"
} 



I suspect that its having a problem with permissions but not sure exactly. I know the file never gets decrypted. I looked into the start-process to use the "-verb RunAS" but cannot figure out how to convert this arguement list that would follow the exe.

Please add more information to your question, as there currently isn't enough to diagnose your problem, ideally in the form of a [mcve]. One thing worth noting is that when you launch a command line from Task Manager, the working directory is C:\Windows\System32.

There is not enough information to help you here. You could add Set-PSDebug -Trace 2, Start-Transcript -Path C:\tmp\logs.logs and maybe set $DebugPreference = 'Continue' too. Also from a personal note, when trying to run a native executable from powershell it is almost always best to use Start-Process or [System.Diagnostics.Process] to avoid strange issues. Yours may very likely be one of them. The call operator & (as well as .\file.exe) are best left to the interactive powershell and ad-hoc commands. Therefore avoid using it within scripts.

@K.Frank: Except in usual circumstances, there is no good reason to use Start-Process. Recommending against using direct invocation of external programs in scripts is a disservice to the community, in my estimation. See the next comment for details.

As an aside: To synchronously execute console applications or batch files in the current console (terminal), call them directly (some.exe or c:\path\to\some.exe ... or & 'c:\path with spaces\to\some.exe' ... or & $exePathStoredInVariable ...). This also allows you to capture their output directly and to later query their exit code via $LASTEXITCODE. Do not use Start-Process (or the System.Diagnostics.Process API it is based on). See this answer and this guidance.

@mklement0 It's just personal experience, it always causes headachs when not wrapping the exe in Start-Process or System.Diagnostics.Process. Especially if you want to have control over the process and not just hand over the entire terminal. Basically pick your poison...

-Verb RunAs is pointless in a scheduled task that runs invisibly : if the task is configured to run with elevation, you don't need it; if it isn't, elevation cannot be achieved in the absence of an interactive user being able to respond to a UAC dialog. To diagnose the problem, capture the output from your gpg.exe call in a file (e.g. ... *>c:\tmp\out.txt - be sure to choose a dir. that the scheduled task is permitted to write to).

-mklement0 note sure I would add to the command to do that
